# Regex but just in substring

Tags: python, regex

I cant find the solution for a regex that looks for a pattern but only in a specific range of the string 
I want to find $ $ but only if it is in the 5-7 position of the string and it doesnt matter which character is between those two

Example

```
xxxx$x$xxxxx would match
xx$x$xxxxxxx would not
```

Comment: Then maybe you can just do `my_string[5] == '$' and my_string[7] == '$'`? (check first `len(my_string) > 7` if necessary)

Comment: `/^.{4}\$.\$/` ...

Comment: This question, if not great, is nevertheless accurate and perfectly answerable. I really don't see how the generic [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) can be considered a duplicate of this one - unless we consider that any regex question can be answered by 'learn regex'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

should = "xxxx$x$xxxxx would match"
shouldnt = "xx$x$xxxxxxx would not"

pattern = r'^.{4}\$.\$.+'

re.match(pattern, should)
re.match(pattern, shouldnt)
```

gives

```
match
None
```

https://regex101.com/r/RLHrZb/1

Comment: Link only answer are useless.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski got it

Comment: that is it, thx alot